# Getting more than 100 users accounts who have liked a tweet

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I need to get the list of users accounts who have liked a tweet.

Reading the documentation of Twitter API, it only returns up to 100 accounts. My question is: Is there another way to get more than 100 accounts with other method?

Comment: I think that's something available to higher level access accounts like in enterprise level.

Comment: I asked twitter support team this, to see what they say. I don't know if the limit applies generally or only for the twitter api v2

Comment: There is no enterprise API that provides this information. The enterprise offerings provide access to historical search, and to additional streaming volumes - not to likes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information on arbitrary past Tweets. If you are the owner of an account you can track the likes using the Account Activity API after you post a Tweet, and can then keep track of the like actions. This would be the way to get the account information for likes on Tweets, beyond the API limit of 100 (which exists in both v1.1 and v2).